# Angular - Having trouble with my .css styles after installing bootstrap

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-5

I'm learning Angular, and i came across this particular problem which i still couldn't fix. I'm using the latest version of Bootstrap on my Angular project but i'm having issues with my styles.css file (which i had already defined before installing Bootstrap). I noticed that some things about my style changed after installing Bootstrap, and i can't fix them no matter how much i edit my styles.css file

Here are some examples:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVOCl.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UpkS.png

I suppose that the bootstrap.min.css file introduced on Bootstrap's installation might be overriding my custom css stylesheet, but i don't really see how.

**This is my index.html file:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Selene Chavez -- Portfolio</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <!--Box Icons-->
  <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
  <!--Box Icons-->
  <!--Bootstrap-->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!--Mis estilos CSS-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/styles.css">

</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

**This is my .css stylesheet:**

```
/* Google Fonts */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap');
* {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    scroll-padding-top: 2rem;
}

/* Variables */
:root {
    --main-color: #F24822;
    --body-color: #090a1a;
    --container-color: #171b3c;
    --heading-color: #222231;
    --box-color: #0d0f26;
    --bg-color: #fff;
}

body {
    color: var(--bg-color);
    background: var(--body-color);
}

html::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0.5rem;
    background: transparent;
}


html::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: var(--heading-color)
}

img {
    width: 100%;
}

section {
    padding: 3rem 0 2rem;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
}

.container {
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

/* Header */
header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
}

.header-active {
    background: var(--box-color);
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.nav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 20px 0;
}

.navbar-logo {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 90px;
}

.navbar-logo img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.navbar {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    column-gap: 1.5rem;
}

.nav-link {
    font-size: 0.94rem;
    padding: 4px 8px;
    border-radius: 0.2rem;
    color: var(--bg-color);
}

.nav-link:hover {
    color: var(--main-color);
    background: var(--container-color);
    transition: 0.3s all linear;
}

/* Menu Icon */
.menu-icon {
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    row-gap: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 200;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.menu-icon div {
    display: block;
    background: var(--bg-color);
    height: 2px;
    width: 24px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.move .line1 {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 5px);
}

.move .line2 {
    opacity: 0;
}

.move .line3 {
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -5px);
}

.home {
    min-height: 600px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top: 7rem;
}

.home-content {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 600px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.home-img {
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #fd7051;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.home-img {
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
}

.home-text {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}

.home-text h3 {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    column-gap: 0.5rem;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    color: var(--main-color);
}

.home-text h3::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%);
    left: -15px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 2px;
    background: var(--main-color);
}

.home-text h3::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%);
    right: -35px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 2px;
    background: var(--main-color);
}

.home-text h2 {
    font-size: 3.5rem;
    line-height: 4.8rem;
}

.home-text p {
    font-size: 0.938rem;
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.home-text .color {
    color: var(--main-color);

}

.social {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    column-gap: 0.5rem;
}

.social .bx {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: var(--bg-color);
    background: var(--container-color);
}

.social .bx:hover {
    background: var(--main-color);
    transition: 0.3s all linear;
}

/* Heading */
.heading {
    font-size: 5rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: var(--heading-color);
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.about-content {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    gap: 1.5rem;
}

.about-data span {
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: var(--main-color);
}

.about-data h2 {
    font-size: 2rem;
    line-height: 2.6rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: 1rem 0;
}

.btn {
    font-size: 0.97rem;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    column-gap: 0.5rem;
    color: var(--bg-color);
    background: var(--main-color);
    padding: 12px 16px;
    border-radius: 0.4rem;
    margin-top: 1rem;
}

.btn .bx {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.btn:hover {
    background: #fd7051;
    transition: 0.3s all linear;
}

.about-text p {
    font-size: 0.938rem;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-align: justify;
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

/* Skills */
.skills {
    padding: 50px 20px;
}

.skills .content-section {
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: auto;
}

.skills .row {
    display: flex;
}

.skills .row .col {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.skills .row .col h3 {
    font-size: 28px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.skills .skill>span {
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.skills .skill .skills-bar {
    height: 8px;
    width: 80%;
    background-color: var(--heading-color);
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.skills .skill .progress {
    background-color: var(--main-color);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 8px;
}

.skills .skill .skills-bar span {
    position: absolute;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    background-color: var(--main-color);
    border-radius: 50px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    top: -17px;
    right: -15px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.skills .skill .javascript {
    width: 0%;
    animation: 2s javascript forwards;
}

@keyframes javascript {
    0% {
        width: 0%;
    }

    100% {
        width: 75%;
    }
}

.skills .skill .htmlcss {
    width: 0%;
    animation: 2s htmlcss forwards;
}

@keyframes htmlcss {
    0% {
        width: 0%;
    }

    100% {
        width: 89%;
    }
}

.skills .skill .python {
    width: 0%;
    animation: 2s python forwards;
}

@keyframes python {
    0% {
        width: 0%;
    }

    100% {
        width: 85%;
    }
}

.skills .skill .mysql {
    width: 0%;
    animation: 2s mysql forwards;
}

@keyframes mysql {
    0% {
        width: 0%;
    }

    100% {
        width: 70%;
    }
}

.skills .skill .photoshop {
    width: 0%;
    animation: 2s photoshop forwards;
}

@keyframes photoshop {
    0% {
        width: 0%;
    }

    100% {
        width: 90%;
    }
}

.skills .skill .comunicacion {
    width: 0%;
    animation: 2s comunicacion forwards;
}

@keyframes comunicacion {
    0% {
        width: 0%;
    }

    100% {
        width: 80%;
    }
}

.skills .skill .trabajoequipo {
    width: 0%;
    animation: 2s trabajoequipo forwards;
}

@keyframes trabajoequipo {
    0% {
        width: 0%;
    }

    100% {
        width: 75%;
    }
}

.skills .skill .creatividad {
    width: 0%;
    animation: 2s creatividad forwards;
}

@keyframes creatividad {
    0% {
        width: 0%;
    }

    100% {
        width: 65%;
    }
}

.skills .skill .autodidacta {
    width: 0%;
    animation: 2s autodidacta forwards;
}

@keyframes autodidacta {
    0% {
        width: 0%;
    }

    100% {
        width: 95%;
    }
}

.skills .skill .productividad {
    width: 0%;
    animation: 2s productividad forwards;
}

@keyframes productividad {
    0% {
        width: 0%;
    }

    100% {
        width: 90%;
    }
}

/* Curriculum */
.estudios {
    padding: 50px 20px;
}

.estudios .content-section {
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: auto;
}

.estudios .row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.estudios .row .col {
    width: 49%;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.estudios .row .col h3 {
    font-size: 28px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.estudios .row .left {
    border-right: 2px solid var(--container-color);
}

.estudios .row .right {
    border-left: 2px solid var(--container-color);
}

.estudios .row .item {
    padding: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    background-color: var(--heading-color);
    position: relative;
}

.estudios .row .item h4 {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.estudios .row .item .institucion {
    color: var(--main-color);
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
}

.estudios .row .item .fecha {
    display: block;
    color: var(--main-color);
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.estudios .row .item p {
    line-height: 24px;
}

.estudios .row .left {
    border-right: 2px solid var(--heading-color);
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.estudios .row .right {
    border-left: 2px solid var(--heading-color);
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.estudios .row .item .connectori {
    height: 2px;
    background-color: var(--main-color);
    width: 47px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: -47px;
    z-index: 5;
}

.estudios .row .item .connectori .circlei {
    display: block;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: var(--main-color);
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 4px;
}

.estudios .row .item .connectord {
    height: 2px;
    background-color: var(--main-color);
    width: 47px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: -47px;
    z-index: 5;
}

.estudios .row .item .connectord .circled {
    display: block;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: var(--main-color);
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 4px;
}

/* Portfolio */
.portfolio-content {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    gap: 2rem;
}

.portfolio-box {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 320px;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.portfolio-img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
}

.portfolio-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: -100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: rgba(59, 40, 22, 0.7);
}

.portfolio-overlay h2 {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.portfolio-overlay .bx {
    font-size: 24px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: var(--main-color);
    color: var(--bg-color);
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.portfolio-overlay .bx:hover {
    background: #fd7051;
    transition: 0.3s all linear;
}

.portfolio-box:hover .portfolio-overlay {
    top: 0;
    transition: 0.3s all ease;
}

/* Contact Form */
.contact-form {
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    row-gap: 1rem;
}

.contact-form input,
.contact-form textarea {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    padding: 15px;
    color: var(--bg-color);
    background: var(--box-color);
    border-radius: 0.4rem;
}

.contact-form .send-btn {
    width: 120px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 12px;
    background: var(--main-color);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.contact-form .send-btn:hover {
    background: #fd7051;
    transition: 0.3s all linear;
}

/* Footer */
.footer {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    row-gap: 1.4rem;
    padding: 30px 0;
}

.footer p {
    font-size: 0.9rem;
}

/* Scroll Top */
.scroll-top {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: -100%;
    right: 1.5rem;
}

.scroll-top .bx {
    padding: 8px;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    color: var(--bg-color);
    background: var(--box-color);
    border-radius: 0.2rem;
}

.scroll-top .bx:hover {
    background: var(--container-color);
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.scroll-active {
    bottom: 2rem;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

/* Responsive */
@media (max-width:990px) {
    .container {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 90%;
    }
}

@media (max-width:892px) {
    section {
        padding: 2rem 0;
    }

    .nav {
        padding: 12px 0;
    }

    .heading {
        font-size: 4rem;
    }

    .portfolio-box {
        height: 257px;
    }
}

@media (max-width:775px) {
    .nav {
        padding: 10px 0;
    }

    .logo {
        font-size: 1.1rem;
    }

    .home {
        min-height: 500px;
        padding-top: 6rem;
    }

    .home-text h3 {
        font-size: 1rem;
    }

    .home-text h2 {
        font-size: 3rem;
        line-height: 3.8rem;
    }

    .home-text p {
        font-size: 0.825rem;
    }

    .skills {
        padding: 10px 50px;
    }

    .skills .row .col h3 {
        font-size: 1rem;
    }

    .estudios .content-section {
        max-width: 600px;
        margin: auto;
    }

    .portfolio-box {
        height: 245px;
    }

    .menu-icon {
        display: flex;
    }

    .navbar {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: -100%;
        width: 300px;
        height: 100vh;
        background: var(--box-color);
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 50px 20px;
        transition: 0.5s all cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
    }

    .open-menu {
        right: 0;
        transition: 0.5s all cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
    }

    .nav-link {
        display: block;
        margin: 1rem 0;
    }
}

@media (max-width:635px) {
    .about-content {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }

    .about-data span {
        font-size: 0.9rem;
    }

    .about-data h2 {
        font-size: 1.7rem;
        line-height: 2.3rem;
        font-weight: 600;
        margin: 0.8rem 0;
    }

    .about-text p {
        font-size: 0.825rem;
        margin-bottom: 1.3rem;
    }

    .estudios .row {
        display: block;
    }

    .estudios .row .col {
        width: 90%;
    }

    .estudios .row .right {
        margin-left: 20px;
    }
}

@media (max-width:450px) {
    .home {
        min-height: 485px;
        padding-top: 5rem;
    }

    .home-img {
        width: 120px;
        height: 120px;
    }

    .home-img img {
        width: 120px;
        height: 160px;
    }

    .home-text h2 {
        font-size: 2.1rem;
        line-height: 3.2rem;
    }

    .home-text p br {
        display: contents;
    }

    .heading {
        font-size: 3rem;
    }

    .about-data h2 {
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        line-height: 2.1rem;
        margin: 0.6rem 0;
    }

    .skills .row {
        display: block;
    }

    .skills .row .col {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .skills .row .col .skills-bar {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .portfolio-content {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }
}

@media (max-width:325px) {
    .navbar {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .portfolio-box {
        height: 190px;
    }
}
```

**The routes on my Angular.json file:**

```
    "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, If you are using Bootstrap npm package , then you shouldn't use cdn bootstrap link in index.html.

In angular.json, you should include both bootstrap css and js , on server object also to use it while creating build.Its now only in test object.

To override your style issue , you can use !important in you style.css where your style is overide by bootstrap classes

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-add-bootstrap-css-framework-to-an-angular-application/